# Pass data to controller from Module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I pass data to controllers from Module class?

I need to pass data from onBootstrap method to all module controllers. What is the best way to do this. I can access controller using `$e->getTarget()` but don't know how to pass custom data to it. Maybe controller has storage for that?

Comment: What data? `module.php` defines the services for the module; If you would like to inject these into the controller then you should create a factory in the `getControllerConfig` method and pass them into the constructor.

Comment: I checking authentification token in module.php and I want to pass that token to controller to save it in logs with additional data. I could get it from request again, but I don't want to do same actions twice.

Comment: Maybe use an event listener and trigger the event in module.php and pass variable that way. Doesn't even need to hit the controller then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller has access to the `MvcEvent` you can setup an event listener to attach arbitrary data to it and then fetch it within the controller.

**Module.php**

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
   $event->setParam('foo', 'bar');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function fooAction() {
  $foo = $this->getEvent()->getParam('foo', false);
}
```

@JonDay suggested an event listener which would also work well.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
   $application  = $event->getApplication();
   $eventManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

   $eventManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($event) {
      $controller = $event->getTarget();

      // Set public property
      $controller->foo = 'bar';

      // OR protected with setter
      $controller->setFoo('bar');

   });
}
```

Comment: You can explicitly call the namespace of the module as identifier. Lukas needs to pass the variable to **all module controllers** i.e. all controllers within a module. The module name (as long as it's a single namespace part) is also an identifier for a dispatchable controller.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to add param to controller instead of event :)

Comment: @JurianSluiman Good point, thanks for correcting (I actually read it as "all controllers"). Lukas, you can swap the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` for `__NAMESPACE__` if you just want to target the controllers in a certain module.

Comment: @AlexP Why Controller's __constructor can't get parameter value of foo? I tried `$this->getEvent()->getParam('foo', false)` in constructor. But the param isn't available.